# How do you set the language in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am trying to use i18n in rails. I want the language to be set first from params[:locale] (probably already in the url) then from the browser http header and lastly from the default_locale. Everything is fine. Now the problem starts, when I want to add a dropdown list to allow the user to change the locale. How do I force the page to reload with the new Locale? 
FYI, I tried using .js and forcing a page.reload. The result was that the it kept the same locale in the url after the reload. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really a JS question. It should be something like this:

```
location.href = location.href + "&locale=" + locale;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [PrototypeHelper#observe_field](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/observe_field) method to generate the Javascript to add the onSelect event.

You can't just reload the page, you have to do a new request to the same url with the new locale.